# size after pointer decay in 2D array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Consider the output of toy program below:

```
void fun(int arr[][3]) {
    cout<<sizeof arr;
}

int main() {
    int arr[5][3];
    cout<< sizeof arr<<" ";
    func(arr);
}
```

As pointer decay happens only once in 2D array, I was expecting the output to be
60 12
as
5*3*4 and   3*4.

But the output is
60 4
Could anyone explain what happened?

Comment: asked so many times, you should google it, `arr` is just a pointer not an array in `fun()`

Comment: `arr[][3]` is a pointer to an array of 3 integers. sizeof a pointer is 4 on 32-bit platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void fun(int arr[][3]);

void fun(int (*arr)[3]);
```

The above are equivalent. In other words, `arr` is a pointer to `int[3]`. So it has the size of a pointer, which happens to be 4 bytes in your case.

Answer (score 2):

in fun()

```
arr[][3]
```

arr is a pointer to array of 3 integers. so the output is sizeof pointer.